# Efficient searching for boundary in discrete parameter space

Tags: algorithm, search, computation

I am looking for an efficient way to map the phase boundary of a 2D parameter space. I currently have some Python code which will compute the state of some system at a given point in the parameter space, and I want to map the curves in this space where the state changes. Such a diagram will resemble the diagram below. Rather than computing the state at every point in some large discretized parameter space, I am looking for an efficient algorithm to search for the phase boundaries, as there will be large regions with no boundary. Additionally, there are regions in the parameter space where different boundaries are quite close together, so a coarse grained search may not work. Does anyone have suggestions on how to search for these boundaries efficiently?

[image: Phase Diagram]

Comment: Suppose you sample at 100 points within a region and get the same answer for each. If all you know is a method for computing the state at a point there is nothing to rule out the possibility that the 101st point might give a different answer. So unless you can tell us something about the state function I don't see how anybody can come up with anything more than computing it at some nice pattern of points.